# Spring connection pooling configurations

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I've been searching around the web for some time now and i've yet to fix this issue:

I have the following datasource configuration:

```
 <bean id="cpms.prod.ds"  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property>
    <property name="url"><value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql</value></property>
    <property name="username"><value>test</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>test</value></property>
    <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="2" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="1"></property>
 </bean>
```

This should be enough to make sure there are only 2 active connections at one point and those are the ones used for the pool.

In my java code i'm using `SimpleJdbcTemplate` to do three queries, and as I understand it this object should be returning the connections to the pool after each query ends, should also be blocking the third query while one of the others end.

When looking at my database administration console I see 3 connections appear, and then change to sleep state. If I run the queries again I see another 3 connections popup and the other 3 stay there.

The only way i've found for the connections to be closed is by setting:

```
<property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
<property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="1"/>

<property name="minIdle" value="0"></property>
<property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1000"></property>
<property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1000"></property>
```

which forces the abandoned connections procedure to run and clean the old connections.

I shouldn't have to meddle with these parameters, and especially not be setting them so low as it might have performance issues.

I've also tried the solution shown [here](https://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/spring-poolable-database-connection/) to the same effect until i change the `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` and `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` to the lower values. And it still doesn't limit the connections to 2.

Comment: Obvious sanity check - your JDBCTemplate is actually using `cpms.prod.ds` as the DataSource, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's the only available datasource

Comment: What version of apache-common-dbcp  use use ? There was an issue with minIdle 0 in early versions https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-379

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. I tested your dbcp setting against commons-dbcp 1.4, mysql-connector-java 5.1.25 and mysql 5.1.44 and the desired behavior occur. I used `select benchmark(5000000, md5('test'))` to simulate long running query. One suspicion is you have duplicate connection pools somewhere

Answer (score 0):

All connections in the JdbcTemplate are via [DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.java#DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection%28javax.sql.DataSource%29). What you are seeing might be due to the 'intelligence' in [BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#getRemoveAbandoned%28%29)

From the API:

`Abandonded connections are identified and removed when getConnection() is invoked and the following conditions hold`:

- `getRemoveAbandoned() = true`
- **getNumActive() > getMaxActive() - 3**
- `getNumIdle() < 2`

The data source seems to allow 3 more active connections than the specified max-active.